# std::move return value of weak_ptr::lock messing up reference count of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

i need an explanation of the following behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    std::string s = "foo";
    std::weak_ptr<A> h;
    std::shared_ptr<A> && getR() {
        return std::move(h.lock());
    }
    std::shared_ptr<A> getL() {
        return h.lock();
    }
};

std::vector< std::shared_ptr<A> > storage;
std::vector< std::weak_ptr<A> > accountant;

void store(std::shared_ptr<A> && rr) {
    std::cout << "store '" << rr->s << "' uses: " << rr.use_count() << std::endl;
    storage.push_back(std::move(rr));
}

int main() {
    // create keeper of A
    auto keeper = std::make_shared<A>();
    keeper->s = "bar";
    // store weak_ptr-type handle with accountant
    accountant.push_back(keeper);
    // backref handle to A
    keeper->h = accountant[0];

    std::cout << "# case 0: manual 'move'" << std::endl;
    {
        store(std::move(accountant[0].lock()));

        std::cout << "uses: " << keeper.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    storage.clear();

    std::cout << "# case 1: manual 'move' from internal" << std::endl;
    {
        store(std::move(keeper->h.lock()));

        std::cout << "uses: " << keeper.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    storage.clear();

    std::cout << "# case 2: return copy from func" << std::endl;
    {
        store(keeper->getL());

        std::cout << "uses: " << keeper.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    storage.clear();
    // all is well up to here.

    std::cout << "# case 3: return rref from func" << std::endl;
    {
        store(keeper->getR());

        std::cout << "uses: " << keeper.use_count() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "storage[0]: " << storage[0].get() << " uses: " << storage[0].use_count() << " " << &storage[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "keeper: " << keeper.get() << " uses: " << keeper.use_count() << " " << &keeper << std::endl;
    }
    storage.clear();

    std::cout << "# after" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "uses: " << keeper.use_count() << std::endl;
    // all the A is gone!!!!
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
# case 0: manual 'move'
store 'bar' uses: 2
uses: 2
# case 1: manual 'move' from internal
store 'bar' uses: 2
uses: 2
# case 2: return copy from func
store 'bar' uses: 2
uses: 2
# case 3: return rref from func
store 'bar' uses: 1
uses: 1
storage[0]: 0x2b49f7a0fc30 uses: 1 0x2b49f7a10ca0
keeper: 0x2b49f7a0fc30 uses: 1 0x7ffd3683be20
# after
uses: 0
```

ideone: http://ideone.com/smt7TX

This is a class holding a weak_ptr to itself, so it can give out shared_ptr-handles to itself. Its a resource-class in the real code, and shared_ptr handles to those get passed around. Now in an effort to reduce copying shared_ptrs i came across my getHandle function (getR/getL in the above) and wanted it to return by moving instead of copying. In a short test std::moving the return of weak_ptr::lock seemed ok, but in the final code it messed things up bad.
In comparison to copying the return-value it seems moving it reduces the shared_ptr's reference counter - so i end up with 2 shared_ptrs in existence but both having a use_count() of 1. so if the one i got using get() goes out of scope the A gets destroyed and my original shared_ptr which is still around points to garbage.
In the example code you can see that after case 3 - i would have expected the last cout to tell me a use_count() of 1 until keeper is destroyed.

Now in the real code i just inlined the equivalent of getL in the hopes that this will prevent the superflous copying, but i can't get over not having a clue why this doesn't work as i thought it would.

Why does case 3 reduce the reference count? 
And then why don't case 0 and 1 also reduce it?

Comment: using `std::move` in a return is normally a pessimization.  If you want a prvalue then just return by value from the function.

Comment: Yes, why are you moving temporaries? You can't make them any more rvaluey than they already are.

Comment: _"This is a class holding a weak_ptr to itself, so it can give out shared_ptr-handles to itself. "_ Why not derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>` and have it work automatically with no extra effort and no reference cycles?

Comment: Jonathan and Nathan, yes... why indeed ... i should have known that. the getHandle function started out bigger and boiled down more and more - as it reached it's final short form i must have been blinded. 
Also thanks for the hint to `std::enable_shared_from_this` that's just what i need!

Comment: While these comments don't exactly answer the question (weird reference counts), i think they show that it's a question that shouldn't have to be asked in the first place.

Comment: The weird reference counts are because you have undefined behaviour, because you return a dangling reference thanks to that `std::move`. It turns an rvalue into a reference to empty space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a bug here:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> && getR() {
    return std::move(h.lock());
}
```

This creates a temporary `shared_ptr` which is local to the function then returns a reference to it. That is a dangling reference to an object that no longer exists. Just return by value as `getL` does (I don't know why you've called it `getL` ... if that refers to an lvalue it's wrong, it returns an rvalue).

You are misusing `std::move` in a misguided attempt to improve performance, but simply returning the object is simpler, safer, and allows the compiler to optimise it far more effectively. Without the `std::move` there won't be any copy *or* move, the compiler will elide the temporary completely, see [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

These other moves are also redundant (although not actually harmful here):

```
    store(std::move(accountant[0].lock()));

    store(std::move(keeper->h.lock()));
```

In both cases you're trying to move something that is already an rvalue, which is pointless.

Also you have reimplemented [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), poorly. Get rid of your `weak_ptr` member and your backref and just do:

```
struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    std::string s = "foo";
};
```

And then call `keeper->shared_from_this()` instead of `keeper->getL()`. You'll notice that `shared_from_this()` returns by value, not by reference, to avoid the bug in your `getR()` function.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.